# How to use Bootstrap Scss with Ruby on Rails to style a list of Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm making a basic Ruby on Rails application where users can make & view posts.

This is the code I use to display posts

```
  <% if @feed_items.any? %>
   <ol class="posts">
<%= render @feed_items %>
 </ol>
<%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
  <% end %>
```

Currently I have seeded each user with about 50 posts for testing and the posts all display in a list like this:

```
Post 1
Post 2
Post 3
Post 4 etc
```

I want to use bootstrap scss to style these posts so instead of the above it is styled more like

```
Post 1              Post 2                Post 3
Post 4
```

Where there are 3 posts in each row, rather than just 1.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how someone very new to bootstrap scss could approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the combination of `in_groups_of` and `bootstrap grid system`

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <% @feed_items.in_groups_of(3).each do |feeds| %>
    <div class="row">
      <% feeds.each do |feed| %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <%= render feed %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: One more question: in my static pages controller I define feed items as:
 @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])

How would I do the same thing without pagination?

Answer (score 0):

I think that `in_groups_of` is a good fit for what you need.

The following code will divide your feed items collection into groups of 3 rows, and then you can format each group of 3 as you like:

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <table>
  <% @feed_items.in_groups_of(3).each do |row_feed| %>
    <tr>
      <% for feed in row_feed %>
        <td><%= feed.title %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```